# Why acts this string so strange, no memory for him?

Tags: c++, string

What is going on with this string? It shouldn't work all the time? To work correctly I must give him a value  (e.g `result = "ManyLetters"`). But when I make it clear then I don't see the correctly value. When I give the string a value with less letters than Hex contains then not all of the Hex will appear.

```
string changeDectoHex(int Dec){

    string result = "";
    int modulo = 0;

    for (int i = 0; Dec != 0; i++){
        modulo = Dec % 16;
        Dec = (Dec - modulo)/16;

        if (modulo == 0) result[i] = '0';
        else if (modulo == 1) result[i] = '1';
        else if (modulo == 2) result[i] = '2';
        else if (modulo == 3) result[i] = '3';
        else if (modulo == 4) result[i] = '4';
        else if (modulo == 5) result[i] = '5';
        else if (modulo == 6) result[i] = '6';
        else if (modulo == 7) result[i] = '7';
        else if (modulo == 8) result[i] = '8';
        else if (modulo == 9) result[i] = '9';
        else if (modulo == 10) result[i] = 'A';
        else if (modulo == 11) result[i] = 'B';
        else if (modulo == 12) result[i] = 'C';
        else if (modulo == 13) result[i] = 'D';
        else if (modulo == 14) result[i] = 'E';
        else if (modulo == 15) result[i] = 'F';
    }

    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());

    return result;
}
```

Comment: `result[i]` is undefined behavior when the string is empty. I think you want to use `result.push_back('1');` and so on.

Comment: Thank you, I see that there's no way without defining the length. Wow! Edit. Man you are my Hero.

Comment: @MatthewZ there is a way, see my answer. It is just not `operator[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `push_back` instead of trying to assign to `result[i]`.  You can `reserve` to the expected amount before-hand if you like to speed things up.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access element out of range (you string has zero length), just use:

```
result += '1';
```

etc. 
You can use another string, to avoid cascade if/else:

```
 result += "0123456789ABCDEF"[modulo];
```